# Is there a way to use ORDER BY and still use deleterow()?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, derby

The code I'm using deletes the last row in the database. From what I have read, once I've used `ORDER BY` it will set the result back to read only which makes `deleterow()` or anything else involving updating the database not possible.

Is there a work around so I could make the table `ORDER BY Score DESC` and still delete the row I need to delete?

```
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Scores";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass= "root";

         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

         String SQLd = "select * from ROOT.HISCORES ORDER BY Score DESC";

         ResultSet dl = stmt.executeQuery( SQLd );

         dl.last();
         dl.deleteRow();

    }
```

Comment: order by only orders the results you see, what makes you think it would change how the data is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like a good practice to me.

Instead of `SELECT`ing data into Java and deleting it from there, just do it at the database level. Do a delete-select and skip most of the Java work.

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM root.hiscores
WHERE Score = (SELECT MIN(hs.Score) FROM root.hiscores hs)
```

Comment: Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "LIMIT" at line 1, column 86.

Comment: HOLD THE PHONE! i removed the LIMIT 1 (limit isn't supported) from the delete statement then put the delete statement in a preparedStatement instead of a resultset. once i did that, it started to work. Thank you @Martin Carney. :D

Comment: @Zetaro666 glad that worked. The `LIMIT 1` is an attempt to ensure only one row is deleted, even if the lowest two scores are the same value.

Comment: It's cool though, even if it deletes two. the possibilities of someone getting the same lowest score are slim. I really only needed it to delete.

Comment: It's probably fine for a prototype or a class assignment, but not for production code. In a production setting, you'd need to guarantee only one record is deleted.